# Inner Join MYSQL Query Combining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, inner-join

How can I combine 3 tables in a INNER JOIN?

The end result I am after is getting a list of CATEGORIES belonging to a PRODUCT - including the CATEGORY'S PARENT ID CATEGORY value (ie: Sneakers and Nike).

The CATEGORIES table and PRODUCTS table are joined in the PRODUCTS & CATEGORIES table. A product can belong to many categories and a category can have many products.

Here's more-or-less the setup I have in my database...

**CATEGORIES TABLE:**

```
CAT ID | PARENT ID | CATEGORY
1      | 0         | Sneakers
2      | 1         | Nike
3      | 2         | Jordan
```

**PRODUCTS TABLE:**

```
PROD ID 
1
2
3
```

**PRODUCTS & CATEGORIES TABLE:**

```
CAT ID | PROD ID
1      | 0
1      | 1
2      | 3
```

I am running these queries and I am getting some results, but at the moment I am running 2 separate queries...

```
$q1 = "SELECT prodid, GROUP_CONCAT(catid SEPARATOR ' // ') as catid FROM products_categories group by prodid order by prodid";
$result1 = $conn->query($q1);

   if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
      while($prods = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "Product Id:" . $prods["prodid"] . " ––> " . "Categories Id:" . $prods["catid"];
      }
   } else {
      echo "0 results";
   }

$q2 =
"  SELECT `ID`.`category` as `IDName`, `LABEL`.`category` as `LabelName`, `LABEL`.`catid` as `LabelId`
   FROM `categories` as ID 
   INNER JOIN `categories` as LABEL
   ON `ID`.`catid` = `LABEL`.`parentid`";
$result2 = $conn->query($q2);

   if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
      while($prods = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "ID# " . $prods["LabelId"] . " is called: ". $prods["LabelName"] . "<br>";
      }
   } else {
      echo "0 results";
   }
$conn->close();
```

I have tried adding another INNER JOIN with no luck in the results.
The end result I am after would be: **PROD ID #0** belongs to **Sneakers, Nike, Jordan**.
Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much,

Sergio

---

**UPDATE - 10/11/16**

The Query:

```
$q =
"  SELECT PC.productid as productid,  concat_WS('~',C1.category, C2.category, C3.category) as breadcrumb
   FROM xcart_categories as C1

   INNER JOIN xcart_products_categories as PC 
      ON C1.categoryid = PC.categoryid

   LEFT JOIN xcart_categories as C2
      ON C1.categoryid = C2.parentid
      AND C1.parentid = 0

   LEFT JOIN xcart_categories as C3
      ON C2.categoryid = C3.parentid
      WHERE C1.parentid = 0
   ";
```

The Fetch:

```
$result = $conn->query($q);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($prods = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $prods['productid'] . ' Belongs in these categories: ' . $prods['breadcrumb'] . '<br>';
      }
   } else {
      echo "0 results";
   }
```

Comment: It looks like categories table is a hierarchy.  MySQL doesn't directly support hierarchical queries.  There are ways to simulate the behavior: which are referenced [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins): (end pointing) :P

Comment: I understand that MYSQL doesn't support hierarchical queries, but isn't the INNER JOIN handling that part of the query? Or am I missing the point of the INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes 3 levels of hierarchy no more and a separate join is needed to "put each record on the same line" so they can be combined into a single value result. I thin you were trying to use Group_concat but I can't see how that's going to work as you don't have a way to walk the hierarchy.

```
SELECT PC.ProductID,  concat_WS('-',C1.Category, C2.Category, C3.Category) as breadcrumb
FROM categories C1
INNER JOIN ProductsCategories PC 
 on C1.categoryID = PC.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN categories C2
 on c1.CategoryID = C2.ParentID
and C1.parentID = 0
LEFT Join Categories C3
 on C2.CategoryID = C3.ParentID
WHERE C1.ParentID = 0
```

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97653a/14/0) example ( this only supports 3 levels deep, but could be altered with added left joins to support a max level but not a undetermined max level..)

I see you're trying to use group concat to bring all the rows for the same product category.productID of 0  to the same line

However as 0 references catID of 1 it would only return "sneakers" on the inner join.  You would need to traverse the tree (all of it) somehow, thus the above, or you have to take multiple trips to the db or use some sort of dynamic SQL or method mentioned in link in comments.

This would be fairly simple in SQL Server, Oracle or other Enterprise RDBMS systems, however without recursive queries or engine specific hierarchy queries, this is no easy feat in MySQL on a single trip.

Maybe I'm missing something so it may help to see the actual expected results for your sample data.  What is the record set look like that you want back?

Comment: Thank you for your help.... The group concat was basically pulling in every category (parent, children, grandchildren etc etc) associated with that particular product and separating it by the "//". That is working good, but I needed to change the category ID (parent, children, grandchildren etc etc), to their actual value (Sneakers, Nike, Jordan) – not the ID number. I will give your example a go.

Comment: the "ID" you mention on the `ON CL1.ID = CL2.ParentID` is that referring to the CAT ID from the CATEGORIES table?

Comment: Here is an image illustrating what I am looking to achieve, plus a more accurate database setup. The top illustrates a sample of a product page...below the product name (License Plate Holder) is the hypothetical path the user took to get to that page. Below that in the gray box is what I am actually trying to accomplish, which is to list out all the other car make, models, and years, this particular license plate also fits/belongs to. Link to image: http://s21.postimg.org/ae70rcp1j/example.jpg

Comment: Updated and added a fiddle which shows productID and the breadcrumbs.

Comment: Thank You xQbert...It is working but is only displaying the products that only go 2 deep, meaning -> Honda - Civic. We have over 300 products and only about 6 of them go 2 deep, and that's the only ones displaying.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.  Since the fiddle shows 3 levels deep and it's working, the problem I would surmise is data isn't as expected.  Look at the categoryID and the ParentID for one that isn't working all I can think of is the data has a non-display character or the data isnt' mapped parent to child as indicated or the parentID is not zero for those records.  Do a length on categoryID and parentID to ensure it's really the 1-2-3 characters you "See"

Comment: Here screenshots directly from the database. Categories Table: https://s21.postimg.org/6tajvu6c7/Screen_Shot_2016_10_01_at_8_00_57_PM.png Categories&Products Table: https://s13.postimg.org/td70ipyl3/Screen_Shot_2016_10_01_at_8_01_55_PM.png I tried tweaking your query around a bit, but no results closer. Thank you again.

Comment: anyway you take a quick peek at the screenshots and see any discrepancies? Thank you so much!

Comment: I would just update the fiddle with the data and then see if it works.  I took some of it and generated an updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/884462/3/0)  which seems to work.   From what I see there's no breaks in the hierarchy (Parent/Child relationship) so it should work...  note the separator must be 1 character but we could use a ~ or something not in data and then replace the ~ with more than 1 if needed.I would also update your original question to show the current PHP/SQL  Maybe the issue is in the PHP not the SQL?

Comment: I see it working beautifully on the fiddle. But for some reason is not behaving correctly on my local machine – I modified it to correspond to the actual data/labels in the real db. I have updated my original post with the actual query I am using and the php data fetch.

Comment: Also, I am using mysqli as the connection type – if it bears any use to this conundrum.

Comment: Just troubling shooting: If you run the query directly against the MYSQL do you get the desired results?  when you say it's NOT behaving correctly on your local machine... does that mean it's not returning any results or that it is returning incorrect results?  Bit vague to troubleshoot.  Walk though the steps that are working and those that are not.

Comment: As it is on the fiddle, on my machine it is only outputting 10 products instead of the 200+ products. I tried changing the php fetch - instead of fect_assoc I used fetch_object, performed a var_dump before while loop, but still got the same 10 products https://s9.postimg.org/il0zsko6n/Screen_Shot_2016_10_12_at_8_56_47_AM.png.

Comment: BUT if I change the INNER JOIN to also be a LEFT JOIN, then I get better results (not perfect, but close). For some reason it is not acquiring the product IDs for the products it did not display prior, but the products that would display if the query was still INNER JOIN, display their id. https://s22.postimg.org/w7tn3w10x/Screen_Shot_2016_10_12_at_8_58_28_AM.png. It almost seems as if it is displaying the categories hierarchy no matter if it has a product id or not.